# How to send email without relationship between two objects

Tags: trigger, singleemailmessage

i am implmented one trigger for If multiple student records and/ or multiple student email records found, send email to student.course having multipul student records based on coursename field. here no relation between course object and student object.
when course having " student.size()>=1 " means how can i send email to student. how to put student size in code. please any one help on this .

my code :

```
     trigger  coursenames on course__c (after insert,after update ) {

   if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){ 

     EmailTemplate ET=[Select id,name from EmailTemplate where name='TEST TEMPLATE' ];           
        Map<String,course_Settings__c> crSettings = course_Settings__c.getAll();          
        Id owdId = Id.valueOf(crSettings.get('OrgWideEmailAddcrssId').Value__c);
        Id conId = Id.valueOf(crSettings.get('TargetObjectConId').Value__c);

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        list<string> crsid=new list<string>();
           for(course__c crs:trigger.new){

           crsid.add(crs.id);
          }

   list<student__c> agsdt= [select id,name,Email__c,studentcourse__c from student__c];           
   list<course__c> crsdt= [select id,name, coursename__c from course__c where id=:crsid];  
        for(student__c ags:agsdt){

         for(course__c crs:crsdt){  
            if(ags.studentcourse__c ==crs.coursename__c){                  
                  if(ags.Email__C ==null){
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                       
                    mail1.setToAddcrsses(new String[] {'test@gmail.com'}); 
                    mail1.setReplyTo('teststudent@gmail.com');
                    mail1.setSenderDisplayName('salesforce CRM');
                    mail1.setSubject('xxxxxxxxxx);
                    mail1.setBccSender(false);
                    mail1.setUseSignature(false);
                    mail1.setHtmlBody('xxxxxxxxxx');                      
                    allmsg.add(mail1);                      

               }
            }

         }


     }

       Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg);

   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate student size

```
Map<String,Integer> courseNameStudentSizeMap=new Map<String,Integer>();//courseName,studentSize
//create a map with coursenames and student sizes
// course1 0
// course2 0
// course3 0
for(course__c crs: crsdt)
{
 courseNameStudentSizeMap.put(crs.coursename__c,0);
}
//increment studentSize map if student has course 
// course1 1
// course2 0
// course3 2
for(student__c std: agsdt)
{
    if(courseNameStudentSizeMap.containsKey(studentcourse__c))
    {
       Integer increment=courseNameStudentSizeMap.get(studentcourse__c)+1;
       courseNameStudentSizeMap.put(studentcourse__c,increment);
    }

}
```

But does not seem like a wise thing to do. Make them related or put StudentSize field on course and increment it when a student enrolls to course.